# Keep column locked from editing unless the input in the corespodnig one was entered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Dear community I'm reaching out to you as I couldn't find any relevant answer to my question in hopes that you will be able to help.

Basically, my case is relatively simple, I have column A and Column B in the specific spreadsheet name XYZ. In column A I have a drop-down list, with the predefined input to chose from. In column B the user is ought to enter a date. The problem is users oftentimes select the value from the dropdown list without entering a corresponding date value. I tried to use data validation - "custom formula is", to lock column A from editing unless the value is entered in column B unfortunately, it overwrites the dropdown list functionality.

So I wonder if there is a way to translate this formula to apps script to be true for any other input value from the dropdown list than "vacant".

[image]

For the sake of the argument, let's say the range in column A is from A15:A95 and B is from B15:B95.

I look forward to hearing from you guys!

Answer (score 1):

#### Force insertion of date with Modal Dialog

Two functions, both server side.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).activate();
    const html = '<input type="date" id="d1" onChange="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => {google.script.host.close();} ).insert(this.value.toLocaleString());" />';
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Enter Date")
  }
}

function insert(v) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().setValue(v)
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Must be a installable onEdit function.  Please do not name it onEdit(e)

Comment: @ Cooper, Cooper thanks sharing your answer!

However, the result I'm aiming for is the other way around. First I want a user to pick a date and then select a value from the drop-down list. If the date is not entered I want column A in the corresponding row to be locked from editing. Meaning you cannot choose the value in column A unless you enter a date in column B.

Let me know if that makes sense to you.

Comment: The question you ask is a bit broad perhaps you can begin the project on your own and when you run into difficulty you can return and asked more narrowly scoped questions.